# display div on hover with animation

Tags: html, css

I have right side fix position div. I want to display it on hover with animation.

What I want to do that if user hover on the whole div the both `span` should come out with slide animation. **BUT** right now the scroll is coming and only one `span` the text(need help) coming out not  `?` mark coming out.

```css
.need-help-qu{
 background-color:#042E49;
 color:#ffffff;
 padding:0px 10px;
 right:0;
 top:40%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 position:absolute;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
.need-help{
 background-color:#06507D;
 color:#ffffff;
 right:-150px;
 top:40%;
 position:absolute;
 padding:5px 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
.need-help-full:hover .need-help {
 right:0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="need-help-full">
 <span class="need-help-qu">?</span>
 <span class="need-help text-sm">NEED A HELP</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That is because you aren't changing the position of `.need-help-qu` during hover. Also, why don't you position the container and change it on hover instead of positioning the elements individually?

Comment: can you please edit my code for better output as you said ?

Comment: how can we change the position of both span on hover

Comment: @David I would rather suggest you use jquery since thats much easier to achieve.

Comment: Yes i m ready to do it with jquery but how can you share code or link ?

Comment: @David: Would you be ok with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k1mfp11e/)?

Comment: @harry it's work but scrolling is still coming

Comment: @HarigovindR Bad boy. CSS animation, especially as simple as this, ought to be encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/54qj09mn/1/)** out.

You were trying to move individual divs so it was proving tricky, just bunch the whole content of `.need-help-full` div together and move it as a whole.

```
<div class="need-help-full">
    <span class="need-help-qu">?</span>
    <span class="need-help text-sm">NEED A HELP</span>
</div>

<style>
.need-help-qu{
    background-color:#042E49;   color:#ffffff;  padding:3px 10px 2px;
    font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;float:left;
}
.need-help{
  float:left;   background-color:#06507D;   color:#ffffff;
    padding:5px 10px;overflow: hidden;
}
.need-help-full{
    right:-123px;  position:fixed;  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;-moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;-o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
    }
.need-help-full:hover{right:0;}
</style>
```

Also I see that you are trying to accomplish this slide in box so mostly it is done using `position:fixed;` and not using `absolute`. Since it is generally "fixed" to the page and not to some container element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".need-help-qu").hover(function(){
    $(".need-help-qu").animate({right: '12px'});
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  }
.need-help-qu{
 background-color:#042E49;
 color:#ffffff;
 padding:0px 10px;
 right:0;
 top:40%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 position:absolute;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
.need-help{
 background-color:#06507D;
 color:#ffffff;
 right:-150px;
 top:40%;
 position:absolute;
 padding:5px 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  
}
.need-help-full:hover .need-help {
 right:40px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="need-help-full">
 <span class="need-help-qu">?</span>
 <span class="need-help text-sm">NEED A HELP</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but that '?'  should also move left. The '?' is just before the 'need help' text.

Comment: If you need that question mark also to move then i suggest you use jquerry so that it will give you the exact output you need

Comment: you mean that '?' mark is also moving right to left with help text?

Comment: @HarigovindR: Shouldn't really be recommending jQuery for everything. This doesn't need jQuery.

Comment: @Harry I find j query really useful so I try to recommend jquery for such effects and UI hacks. I know reffering an external library is not a good practice. But still. And also its just a suggestion and suggestion can be accepted or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following way. Make parent component `overflow:hidden`. and move `need-help-full` left/right on hover and give absolute position to `need-help-full` div.

```css
.need-help-qu {
    background-color: #042e49;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.need-help {
    background-color: #06507d;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    right: -150px;
}
.need-help-full {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -135px;
    top: 40%;
  
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
.need-help-full:hover {
 right:0;
}


body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="need-help-full">
 <span class="need-help-qu">?</span>
 <span class="need-help text-sm">NEED A HELP</span>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.